# How to identify repeat number format like 111, 444.xy, 8888 etc

Tags: numbers, repeat

Dear Friends,
How to identify the repeat numbers like
111     , Y
122     , N
444     , Y
444.xy  , Y       # xy is any number
9999    , Y

Answer (score 0):

Maybe converting the int to a string and going through each character of the string to check if they are all same. But i do also think there may be a better approach to this problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).